# How to start application after login on CentOS?

Tags: centos, upstart

I am trying to start GUI application with upstart script on CentOS. I have test script located /etc/init/ folder.

```
start on desktop-session-start
stop on desktop-shutdown

respawn

script
export DISPLAY=:0
sleep 5
exec /.1/Projects/UpstartTest/start.sh &

end script
```

start.sh scripts is running binary files for GUI application.

After reboot my computer. When I typed:

```
[root@mg-CentOS ~]# initctl status test
test stop/waiting
```

So my upstart is not runnig. When i type

> initctl start test

manually it works fine without any problem.

How can I run this upstart script after user login (desktop started) ? 
I am trying to find detailed documents for CentOS for upstart but there is no.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On [centos](/questions/tagged/centos) 7 use `gnome-session-properties` to edit this in the GUI:

[image: example]

This will add a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart/`.
You can also alternatively copy the `.desktop` file yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Auto-start apps / services are scattered out there...

To list all Auto-Start **Applications**, search for *autostart*:

```
ls -1 "/etc/xdg/autostart" "/home/$USER/.config/autostart" \
"/usr/share/gdm/autostart"  "/usr/share/gnome/autostart"
```

To list all Auto-Start **Services**:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service
# OR search for:
ls -1 /lib/systemd/system/*.service /etc/systemd/system/*.service
```

To list all **Init** scripts:

```
ls /etc/init.d/
```

To list all **CronTab** schedulers:

```
crontab -l 
# to edit run: crontab -e
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer if you're using the command line.

Comment: Do all services from `/etc/init.d/` start at boot?

Answer (score 1):

I would hazard a guess that it fails to start because it has no X Session.  Although you've told it to use `DISPLAY:0` that display is currently used by you and not the `upstart` service.

Basically, `upstart` isn't designed for starting applications - it's designed to start system services.

Instead, you can create `*.desktop` entries in `~/config/autostart` and I believe [`gnome-tweak-tool`](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/GnomeTweakTool?action=show&redirect=GnomeTweakTool) can also manage startup applications.

The `*.desktop` entry will be similar to:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyCoolScript
GenericName=A really cool script
Comment=Some description about your script
Exec=/.1/Projects/UpstartTest/start.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

More details on the spec is available at the [Gnome developer website](https://developer.gnome.org/autostart-spec/).

Comment: `gnome-tweak-tool` 3.8.1 on centos 7 does not do this.

Answer (score 0):

> **Using cron worked for me on my Centos 7 server.**

```
# enter crontab edit
crontab -e

# place this inside the cron file you opened with the previous command
@reboot /path/to/your/script.sh
```

Remember to make your script executable.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The picture shows my CentOS7 machine runnning the MATE destkop.]

The command in the terminal:

```
mate-session-properties
```

Works for those users running the MATE desktop, it opens up the 'Startup Application Preferences' tab, click the ADD button and enter the name/launch command/comment. I have used the example of Google Chrome and that command runs it for me.

For gnome users, the command in the terminal:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

Brings up the same dialogue for gnome.

The picture shows my CentOS7 machine runnning the MATE destkop.